# What are the requirements to vote in the community moderator nomination?

Tags: support, election

I can't vote in the [community moderator nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election). In fact, I can't even see the arrows or current vote count for each of the candidates.
What are the requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's currently just in the Nomination phase meaning people suggest themselves and explain why they will be good moderators.

Our votes will be accepted in the final phase (Election).

In the current phase of Nomination you can:

1. Add yourself as candidate.
2. See who else is nominee.
3. Post comments on existing candidates.

Comment: Ah ok, cool. Thanks for the quick answer! :)

Answer (score 5):

The election is currently in the nomination phase, so there isn't any voting to be done yet.

The primaries will be held in five days on 2011-11-04 and will require 150 reputation to vote in, followed by the final election period on 2011-11-18.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the information.

Comment: +1, this is the correct answer as to what the requirements are.

Answer (score 2):

During the nomination phase you don't vote for the candidates; the first thirty candidates, ordered by their reputation, pass to the primary phase.
In the next two phases ("primary" and "election"), users with a reputation of at least 150 can vote for who they want to be one of the new community moderators.